# Installing Kali 2.0 on virtual box failled

Tags: kali-linux, authentication

I'm using VirtualBox 4.3.22 and I'm trying to install Kali 2.0. After the installation progress is complete and I reboot, I have to enter my username and password as usual, e.g `username newbie; password bubble29`.

when I'm trying to install, at the begin I have to enter them, but after that when I boot and use the same info, the system doesn't recognize the password. I'm entering the username and everything is good but when I do the same with password it says that sing failed.

Any suggestions? I tried also Linux mint 17.2 to install but I have the same problem.

Comment: Try to type the password as if you have a qwerty keyboard... It might just be a layout problem...

Comment: I tried but nothing happend

Comment: I'm still suspecting a layout problem, either during install or after. if you type your password for the "login" do you see it as intended? Try it upon installation and also after first boot.

Comment: What do you mean exactly as "intended"???

Comment: I mean let's assume your password is azerty.  Type it in the login part. What do you read? "azerty" (as *intended*) or "qwerty" or something else. Repeat this during the installation and after first boot.

Comment: Well just to inform you, I'm newbie Linux user so maybe I will not be able to understand something that you will say, so if you can please be more analytical. For the password now the only thing that can tell you is that any of the passwords I used when I were trying to install Kali failed on the login screen e.g if I use Kali as username and azerty as the "intended" password it will fail, the message that appears says " Sorry that didn't work.Please try again". So I guess that the password "azerty" don't work and the system recognize something else. Sorry if I'm not cooperating very well.

Comment: I was a bit quick and English is not my mother tongue. Maybe try again first to install Linux Mint. It is more accessible to people new to Linux. Try to use a simple password during installation with no special letters (plain ASCII). Install it and reboot. If it works, try to change your password again to what you want. Note that most tools in Kali are also available for installation in Mint. Learn to use Mint and once you're more familiar with Linux you could try again Kali.

Comment: Well thank you, you were right about the layout, I'm a greek guy so upon the instalation i had to choose greek language before enter the password on english, but can you tell me the command to install also a greek language pack so i can have both languages?

Comment: I had similar problem with keyboard. During install, i strike pirla on my AZERTY keyboard, but install takes it as a QWERTY and registers pirlq. Then i must use pirlq on my AZERTY keyboard to login my linux. Same thing for password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, this problem was due to a keyboard layout settings during installation.

As for your secondary question, to have the graphical (and console) interface in Greek and not English, you simply need to reconfigure your "locales" `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, if i need something else should i ask the community or you cause i don't know how to send inbox messages

Comment: @Sentinel you can ask the community. There are many things for which I don't have an answer. And as I'm part of here I could probably see your next question. And then the answers here could benefit someone else having the same problem as you :-) By the way if you're satisfied with the answer could you mark it as answered? It benefits me and also people looking for the same thing as you as they can quickly see that your problem found a solution. Thank you